# Feature Selection in caret rfe + sum with ROC

Tags: r, svm, r-caret, auc, rfe

I have been trying to apply recursive feature selection using caret package. What I need is that ref uses the AUC as performance measure. After googling for a month I cannot get the process working. Here is the code I have used:

```
library(caret)
library(doMC)
registerDoMC(cores = 4)

data(mdrr)

subsets <- c(1:10)

ctrl <- rfeControl(functions=caretFuncs, 
                   method = "cv",
                   repeats =5, number = 10,
                   returnResamp="final", verbose = TRUE)

trainctrl <- trainControl(classProbs= TRUE)

caretFuncs$summary <- twoClassSummary

set.seed(326)

rf.profileROC.Radial <- rfe(mdrrDescr, mdrrClass, sizes=subsets,
                            rfeControl=ctrl,
                            method="svmRadial",
                            metric="ROC",
                            trControl=trainctrl)
```

When executing this script I get the following results:

```
Recursive feature selection

Outer resampling method: Cross-Validation (10 fold) 

Resampling performance over subset size:

Variables Accuracy  Kappa AccuracySD KappaSD Selected
     1   0.7501 0.4796    0.04324 0.09491         
     2   0.7671 0.5168    0.05274 0.11037         
     3   0.7671 0.5167    0.04294 0.09043         
     4   0.7728 0.5289    0.04439 0.09290         
     5   0.8012 0.5856    0.04144 0.08798         
     6   0.8049 0.5926    0.02871 0.06133         
     7   0.8049 0.5925    0.03458 0.07450         
     8   0.8124 0.6090    0.03444 0.07361         
     9   0.8181 0.6204    0.03135 0.06758        *
    10   0.8069 0.5971    0.04234 0.09166         
   342   0.8106 0.6042    0.04701 0.10326         

The top 5 variables (out of 9):
nC, X3v, Sp, X2v, X1v
```

The process always uses Accuracy as performance mesure. Another problem that arises is that when I try to get prediction from the model obtained using:

```
predictions <- predict(rf.profileROC.Radial$fit,mdrrDescr)
```

I get the following message

```
In predictionFunction(method, modelFit, tempX, custom = models[[i]]$control$custom$prediction) :
  kernlab class prediction calculations failed; returning NAs
```

turning out to be imposible to get some prediction from the model.

Here is the information obtained through `sessionInfo()`

```
R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=es_ES.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=es_ES.UTF-8       
 [4] LC_COLLATE=es_ES.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=es_ES.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=es_ES.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=es_ES.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C              
 [10] LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=es_ES.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
 [1] grid      parallel  splines   stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] e1071_1.6-2     class_7.3-9     pROC_1.6.0.1    doMC_1.3.2      iterators_1.0.6 foreach_1.4.1  
 [7] caret_6.0-21    ggplot2_0.9.3.1 lattice_0.20-24 kernlab_0.9-19 

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] car_2.0-19         codetools_0.2-8    colorspace_1.2-4   compiler_3.0.2     dichromat_2.0-0   
 [6] digest_0.6.4       gtable_0.1.2       labeling_0.2       MASS_7.3-29        munsell_0.4.2     
 [11] nnet_7.3-7         plyr_1.8           proto_0.3-10       RColorBrewer_1.0-5 Rcpp_0.10.6       
 [16] reshape2_1.2.2     scales_0.2.3       stringr_0.6.2      tools_3.0.2
```

Answer (score 7):

One problem is a minor typo (`'trControl='` instead of `'trainControl='`). Also, you change `caretFuncs` after you attached it to `rfe`'s control function. Lastly, you will need to tell `trainControl` to calculate the ROC curves.

This code works:

```
 caretFuncs$summary <- twoClassSummary

 ctrl <- rfeControl(functions=caretFuncs, 
                    method = "cv",
                    repeats =5, number = 10,
                    returnResamp="final", verbose = TRUE)

 trainctrl <- trainControl(classProbs= TRUE,
                           summaryFunction = twoClassSummary)
 rf.profileROC.Radial <- rfe(mdrrDescr, mdrrClass, 
                             sizes=subsets,
                             rfeControl=ctrl,
                             method="svmRadial",
                             ## I also added this line to
                             ## avoid a warning:
                             metric = "ROC",
                             trControl = trainctrl)


 > rf.profileROC.Radial

 Recursive feature selection

 Outer resampling method: Cross-Validated (10 fold) 

 Resampling performance over subset size:

  Variables    ROC   Sens   Spec   ROCSD  SensSD  SpecSD Selected
          1 0.7805 0.8356 0.6304 0.08139 0.10347 0.10093         
          2 0.8340 0.8491 0.6609 0.06955 0.10564 0.09787         
          3 0.8412 0.8491 0.6565 0.07222 0.10564 0.09039         
          4 0.8465 0.8491 0.6609 0.06581 0.09584 0.10207         
          5 0.8502 0.8624 0.6652 0.05844 0.08536 0.09404         
          6 0.8684 0.8923 0.7043 0.06222 0.06893 0.09999         
          7 0.8642 0.8691 0.6913 0.05655 0.10837 0.06626         
          8 0.8697 0.8823 0.7043 0.05411 0.08276 0.07333         
          9 0.8792 0.8753 0.7348 0.05414 0.08933 0.07232        *
         10 0.8622 0.8826 0.6696 0.07457 0.08810 0.16550         
        342 0.8650 0.8926 0.6870 0.07392 0.08140 0.17367         

 The top 5 variables (out of 9):
    nC, X3v, Sp, X2v, X1v
```

For the prediction problems, you should use `rf.profileROC.Radial` instead of the `fit` component:

```
 > predict(rf.profileROC.Radial, head(mdrrDescr))
       pred    Active  Inactive
 1 Inactive 0.4392768 0.5607232
 2   Active 0.6553482 0.3446518
 3   Active 0.6387261 0.3612739
 4 Inactive 0.3060582 0.6939418
 5   Active 0.6661557 0.3338443
 6   Active 0.7513180 0.2486820
```

Max

Comment: Thank you for you comments, but fixing the typo don't fix the problem in my case. Accuracy performance measure is used again, as well as the problem with predictions is not solved.

Comment: I accidentally left two things out. I've updated the code above.

Comment: So,  trainControl object is passed directly from rfe() to train() in each size iteration. Therefore, is it correct to suppose that all the rest of params for train() can be modified in the same way?

Comment: @topepo, won't be necessary in SVM to pre-process the data? if yes, would it be passed inside the `rfe()` also? other issue for the `rfeControl` won't be necessary to pass `method="repeatedcv"` instead of `method="cv"` only, since repeated CV was intended?

Comment: Hi, when you have a chance, can you look at this question? this is also related to RFE, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50691553/r-using-my-own-model-in-rferecursive-feature-elimination-to-pick-important-fea

Comment: It seems that trainControl(classProbs= TRUE, summaryFunction = twoClassSummary) tells the R to consider ROC