# feature selection function in caret package

Tags: r, classification, r-caret

I am posting this because this post[feture selection in caret](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21088825/feature-selection-in-caret-rfe-sum-with-roc) hasent helped my issue and I have 2 questions regarding feature selection function in caret package

when I run code below on my  matrix of gene expression `allsamplecombat` with 5 classes defined in `y=` :

`control <- rfeControl(functions=rfFuncs, method="cv", number=10)
results <- rfe(t(allsamplecombat[filter,]), y = factor(info$clust), sizes=c(300,400,500,600,700,800,1000,1200), rfeControl=control)`

I get an out put like this

[image: output of rf]

So, I want to know if I can extract top features for each classes, because `predictors(results)` just give me the resulting feature without indicating importance for each classes.

my second problem is that when i try to change `rfeControl functions` to `treebagFuncs` and run 'parRF` method

`control <- rfeControl(functions=treebagFuncs, method="cv", number=5)
results <- rfe(t(allsamplecombat[filter,]), y = factor(info$clust), sizes=c(400,500,600,700,800), rfeControl=control, method="parRF")`
i get `Error in { : task 1 failed - "subscript out of bounds"` error.

what is wrong in my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the importances, there is a sub-object called `variables` that contains this information for each step of the elimination.

`treebagFuncs` is designed to work with `ipred`'s `bagging` function and isn't related to random forest.

You would probably used `caretFuncs` and pass `method` to that. *However*, if you are going to parallelize something, do it to the resampling loop and not the model function. This is generally more efficient. Note that if you do both with `M` workers, you might actually get `M^3` (one for `rfe`, one for `train`, and one for `parRF`). There are options in `rfe` and `train` to turn their parallelism off.